# Boost.Python demo error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying out Boost.Python demo,

with envs:

- Ubunut 16.04
- Python 3.5.2 alias default
- Boost 1.66.0 src install

  ```
  sudo apt install python3-dev build-essential
  ./bootstrap.sh --with-python=python3.5 
  ./b2
  sudo ./b2 install
  ```

when doing the demo:

```
#include <boost/parameter/keyword.hpp>
#include <boost/parameter/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/parameter/python.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

// First the keywords
BOOST_PARAMETER_KEYWORD(tag, title)
BOOST_PARAMETER_KEYWORD(tag, width)
BOOST_PARAMETER_KEYWORD(tag, height)

class window
{
public:
    BOOST_PARAMETER_MEMBER_FUNCTION(
      (void), open, tag,
      (required (title, (std::string))
      (optional (width, (unsigned), 400) (height, (unsigned), 400))
    )
    {
        printf("Open An New Windows %s of Width %u & height %u \n", title, width, height);
    }
};

struct open_fwd
{
    template <class A0, class A1, class A2>
    void operator()( boost::type<void>, window& self, A0 const& a0, A1 const& a1, A2 const& a2 )
    {
        self.open(a0, a1, a2);
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    namespace py = boost::parameter::python;
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

    class_<window>("window")
        .def(
            "open", py::function<
                open_fwd
              , mpl::vector<
                    void
                  , tag::title(std::string)
                  , tag::width*(unsigned)
                  , tag::height*(unsigned)
                >
            >()
        );
}
```

I got output:

```
parameter.cpp:52:0: error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "BOOST_PARAMETER_MEMBER_FUNCTION"
 }
 ^
In file included from parameter.cpp:3:0:
/usr/local/include/boost/parameter/python.hpp: In function ‘PyObject* boost::parameter::python::aux::unspecified_type()’:
/usr/local/include/boost/parameter/python.hpp:66:7: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘Py_ssize_t {aka long int}’ [-fpermissive]
       };
       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/parameter/python.hpp:66:7: error: invalid conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/local/include/boost/parameter/python.hpp:68:23: error: ‘PyTypeObject {aka struct _typeobject}’ has no member named ‘ob_type’
       if (unspecified.ob_type == 0)
                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/parameter/python.hpp:70:23: error: ‘PyTypeObject {aka struct _typeobject}’ has no member named ‘ob_type’
           unspecified.ob_type = &PyType_Type;
                       ^
parameter.cpp: At global scope:
parameter.cpp:15:5: error: ‘BOOST_PARAMETER_MEMBER_FUNCTION’ does not name a type
     BOOST_PARAMETER_MEMBER_FUNCTION(
     ^
parameter.cpp:15:5: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
parameter.cpp:15:5: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
```

The question is, how to solve "‘PyTypeObject {aka struct _typeobject}’ has no member named ‘ob_type’" error.